# Why is my display() method not printing out all ArrayList elements?

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I have a class Container where a user should be able to input any number of words until he types nothing. I have **addWord(Word)** method where each input is added to an **ArrayList** words every time do/while loop is run. I am passing user input value as a parameter to addWord() method each time loop runs.

Now I want to to display all elements of an array using **display()** method once the do/While loop has stopped running. But for some reason when i try to call method display(), it just shows an empty array [].

Is there any way you can help?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;                                             
import java.util.List;                                              
public class Container {                                                
    private List<String> words;                                             
    public Container() {                                                
    }                                               
    public List<String> getWords() {                                                
        return words;                                               
    }                                               
    public void setWords(List<String> words) {                                              
        this.words = words;                                             
    }                                               
    public void addWord(String word) {                                              
      words = new ArrayList<String>();                                              
      words.add(word);                                          
    }                                               
    public void display() {                                             
      System.out.println(words);                    
    }                                               
}
```

Main method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;                                               
public class ContainerMain                                              
{                                               
  public static void main(String[] args)                                                
  {                                             
    Container one = new Container();                                                
    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);                                    
    String word = "s";                          
    do                                              
      {                                             
        word = myScan.nextLine();                                               
        one.addWord(word);                                              
      }                                             
    while (!word.equals(""));

    if (word.equals("")) {                                              
      one.display();                                                
    }                                               
    else {                                              
      System.out.println("No hope fam");                
    }                                               
  }                                             
}
```

Comment: You re-initialize your ArrayList every time method addWord is called. You will have only the word that was passed in the last call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your `addWord` method:

```
public void addWord(String word) {                                              
  words = new ArrayList<String>();                                              
  words.add(word);                                          
}
```

Each time you call that, it's going to create a new list - so you can *never* end up with more than one word in it.

The first line, initializing `words`, should be in your constructor (or as a field initializer). Then remove the line from `addWord` - ideally making the `words` field final at the same time, to avoid mistakes like this in the future, and remove the `setWords` method unless you really need it for something else.

That's all that wrong in `Container` (although it's not clear that it's really providing any value beyond just using a `List<String>` directly). As noted in comments, currently your do/while loop in `main` will add an empty string at the end. Also, there's no point in checking whether `word` is empty or not *after* the loop - it has to be, otherwise you wouldn't have exited the loop!

Comment: Also the do-while part will add an empty string into ArrayList as word.

Comment: @Ladislav_M: True. Will make a note of that in the answer.

Comment: thanks guys :)  Also to avoid printing last empty string, should i just delete the last array element before calling display() or is there any better way?

Comment: @Joe If you are a beginner simplest solution would be to call .trim() method on the input and see if the length is greater than zero, if it is add it to the ArrayList.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()

Comment: @Joe: There are various different approaches, but that's really a different matter to what you were asking about. I suggest you try various things and ask a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: I just added words.remove(""); in addWord(). Worked perfectly find thanks all appreciate ur help :)